# android - CountDownTimer within ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

I would like to get counter, text and image in ProgressDialog. I managed to get text & image but struggling with getting counter displayed.
I would like to get something like this:

[image]

so i am missing counter from above, can someone help please?

**MainActivity.java**

```
        TextView mTextView_timeCounter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_ah);

        StorageSingleton.getInstance().setString(null, null);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this, R.layout.countdown);
        progress.setCancelable(false);

        //for displaying counter
        mTextView_timeCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTimerTextView);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this, R.layout.countdown);

        progress.setCancelable(false);

        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.timer_logo));


        new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                String countdown = String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60);
                progress.setMessage(countdown);

                progress.setContentView(R.layout.countdown);

                mTextView_timeCounter.setText(countdown);// <- this line causing error

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();

        progress.show();
```

with error:

`PID: 31908 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` this is caused by line

`mTextView_timeCounter.setText(countdown);`
but i don't know why. please find code below

**Countdown.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="35dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Test in Progress..."
    android:textColor="@color/sample12"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/testInProgress"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:src="@drawable/timer_logo"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="hourglass"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myTimerTextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:text=""/>
```

Comment: `mTextView_timeCounter` is uninitialised. You must initialise it inside `onTick` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value .

You should pass **View Object** .

```
progress.setContentView(R.layout.countdown);
mTextView_timeCounter = (TextView)progress.findViewById(R.id.myTimerTextView);
mTextView_timeCounter.setText(countdown);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to `mTextView_timeCounter = (TextView) progress.findViewById(R.id.myTimerTextView);`

You are find view in activity layout but textview in countdown